# function overriding is quite working when called with web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

```
function getDetails(address publicKey) public view returns (Organization memory) {
    return s.getOrg(publicKey);
}

function getDetails(string calldata orgID) external view returns (Organization memory) {
    return s.getOrg(orgID);
}
```

so when i call this  function from remix it works like charm but when i try to call it from my DAPP with web3 it shows error

> invalid address (arg="publicKey", coderType="address", value="653e4140-da2205-13331e9-d44495f4-53a781aaaa1a23")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't support polymorphism on the parameters when calling a function. With web3.js v1.xx you can specify the signature of the method you want to call. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12

```
myContract.methods['getDetails(string)'](..)
```

o

```
myContract.methods['getDetails(address)'](..)
```